# Plot legend text doesn't fit

Tags: r, plot, legend

I have problem with size of my legend. The values in this legend are very small like 2e-18 (an example below) and they take up a lot of space. What can I do in this situation?

[image]

Comment: Please provide example data, and code you have used to produce this plot (legend). Is it base R, ggplot?

Comment: Maybe read about `prettyNum()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the `keywidth` property, to make the legend take up more space, or set a smaller font via the `label.theme` setting (see the [online help](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guide_legend.html)).